# How to query only accounts that don't have attachments

Tags: apex, soql, data, developer

Use Case: get all accounts that don't have a related attachment
I have used this query but I get an error when I add the Bold part

`SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunities WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won'),(SELECT Title,ParentId FROM CombinedAttachments) FROM Account Where Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won') AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ParentId FROM CombinedAttachments)`

The bold part below throws the error shown in the image below

**AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ParentId FROM CombinedAttachments)**

[image: ERROR]

Comment: It seems like your query that originated the screenshot is not quite the same as the one in your post. In your screenshot, it says `ID IN NOT` instead of `NOT IN`. I'm not sure if this is what caused the error though.

Answer (score 2):

`CombinedAttachments` (note the plural) is the name of a relationship. [`CombinedAttachment`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_CombinedAttachment.htm) is the name of the sObject.

You'd use the relationship name when performing a subquery. When you perform a semi-join in your `WHERE` clause, as in your bolded text here, you must use the actual sObject API name.

You've also got `IN NOT` instead of `NOT IN`, as was pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for that @David, I was unaware that this ever existed.

Comment: after fixing the query i got this error : INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION: entity type CombinedAttachment does not support query.

Comment: Then you'll need to build other queries using the underlying objects, Attachment and ContentDocumentLink.